# Ask about Cauchy sequences

Tags: real-analysis

I would be very grateful if you could help me, I have a question about the Cauchy sequences, they have given me the definition that a Cauchy sequence if:

A sequence $(r_{n})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is of Cauchy if:

$\forall \epsilon>0,$ $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that if $n,m>N$, then $|r_{n}-r_{m}|<\epsilon$

My question is, I found a different definition in another book and I would like to know how they are equivalent since the second definition I see as only limits the difference in the sequences. But I think I am wrong and I would like to know how they are equivalent definitions.

The other definition I found is:

A secuence $(r_{n})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is Cauchy if given $\epsilon>0$, there exists a positive integer $m$ such that:

$|r_{n}-r_{m}|<\epsilon\,,$  $[n>m$

first of all, Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prove the second definition from the first, you just need to fix $m=N+1,$and then $|a_n-a_m|<\epsilon$ for all $n>m$.So the second holds if the first holds.

To prove the first from the second, fix $\epsilon>0,$ choose $N$ such that $|a_n-a_N|\le \epsilon/2$ for all $n>N$.Then for all $n,m>N$,we have by triangle inequality$$|a_n-a_m|=|a_n-a_N+a_N-a_m|\le |a_n-a_N|+|a_m-a_N|\le 2*\epsilon/2=\epsilon.$$So the first holds if the second holds.

So the two definitions are equivalent.

Comment: "...choose  such that $|_−_|≤/2$ for all >" here it would not be n> N?

Comment: Oh sorry it is a mistake,you are right, the $n>m$ should be $n > N.$Thanks for pointing out this mistake.

Answer (score 1):

They are equivalent. If the second condition is satisfied then $|r_k-r_j| \leq |r_k-r_m|+|r_m-r_j| <2 \epsilon$ for all $j,k >m$. Do you now see the equivalence of the two definitions?